# Finding last line within node with XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath

I was wondering if there was a way to always select the content of a node above a certain element?

I have the following code that I want to extract from:

```
<div id="someDiv">
   <h3>Name</h3>
   Some content1
   <br/>
   <br/>
   Address 12345
   <br/>
   09876 City, Country
   <br/>
   <span id="tel_number">12345</span>
</div>
```

Here is the XPath that finds the content of everything above the span:

```
//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::node()
```

Now, what I need is an XPath that always selects the content right above the span and nothing else(a single line). It should also work if (for some reason) the `<br/>` above the span was missing.

Hope that somebody can help with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to retrieve the postcode is as follows:

```
data = page.search('(//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::node()').map{|data| data.text.cleanup}
data.delete("")
postcode = data.last.match(/\d{5}/).to_s
```

From there its easy to retrieve everything after or before the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()]
```

or if you want to remove whitespace

```
normalize-space((//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()])
```

Comment: on my machine, with Python and lxml, not Ruby, it gives `'09876 City, Country'`

Comment: I also didn't use `Ruby` for that, I tested [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output). Its simple and pure `xpath` calculations.

Comment: (//[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()] seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but it turns out, that (//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()] doesn't return the right thing. (//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()-3] does, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: When I test on the [page indicated by @Babai](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output), `(//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text())[last()]` is working (note the outer brackets before the `[last()]`; without the outer brackets, you can use @Babai's `//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]`. I haven't tested with Ruby. I don't know if it's XPath engine dependent.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve "09876 City, Country" stripped of any HTML-tags

I think the below you are looking for:

```
//div[@id="someDiv"]/span[@id="tel_number"]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

Using `Nokogiri` :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-EOT
<div id="someDiv">
   <h3>Name</h3>
   Some content1
   <br/>
   <br/>
   Address 12345
   <br/>
   09876 City, Country
   <br/>
   <span id="tel_number">12345</span>
</div>
EOT

doc.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@id='someDiv']/span[@id='tel_number']/preceding-sibling::text()[1])").to_s
# => "09876 City, Country"
```

Comment: That just returns the element itself? [3] returns the right line. But this is way to specific. I was looking for a more general approach like the use of [last()], just for content within a node.

Comment: @Severin ok.. can you tell me what value you want? only the text or element? That's not clear.. mention the output you are looking for.

Comment: I want to retrieve "09876 City, Country" stripped of any HTML-tags.