# XPath ambiguity

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xpath

I am working with the following fragment of an XPath

```
ancestor::contribution[1]/preceding-sibling::contribution[@speaker-reference][1]
```

My Java application (using JDOM for XPath queries) interprets this differently from our Oracle database (11g).
I was able to solve the problem by using brackets as follows:

```
 (ancestor::contribution[1]/preceding-sibling::contribution[@speaker-reference])[1]
```

So it seems that JDOM is reading the xpath as "the first of all preceding `contributions` with an attribute `@speaker-reference`" while Oracle thinks "the preceding `contribution` with an attribute `@speaker-reference and position()=1`".

I had actually intended the first interpretation. I am wondering which of the two interpretations is correct according to the XPath specification (couldn't find the right place to look) or whether the specification allows expressions to be ambiguous.

Comment: can't you add a short XML example and show what you expect to be selected, and what JDOM and Oracle actually select. It's hard to follow your analysis without an example.

Comment: wero is right: There is more than one potential reason why the two implementations could be differing, e.g. reverse direction of the axis, and binding precedence. Without sample XML (with several `<contribution>` elements) it's hard to be sure that your analysis of how JDOM and Oracle DB are working is correct and complete, or to verify which implementation is wrong. I'm pretty sure it's not a matter of XPath ambiguity.

Comment: See also my question/answer about how the reverse axis affects the meaning of position predicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18524097/423105

Answer (score 3):

According to the [XML Path Language Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-precedence-order), square brackets operator `[..]` has precedence 19, while slash `/` has precedence 18. This means that the last square brackets `[1]` should be applied to the portion of the expression after the slash `/`, not to the entire expression. In other words, Oracle's interpretation is right.

Java's implementation<sup>*</sup>, which gives you the correct result without parentheses around the `/` expression, is not compliant with the standard. Consider filing a bug with a short example and an explanation of what is going on.

<sup>*</sup> Ironically, that's Oracle's implementation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Given your description it is not easy to see what JDOM and Oracle are doing.
But their different behaviour is apparently caused by a different implementation of the [proximity position](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) of a reverse axis.

Since `ancestor::contribution[1]` evaluates to an empty node-set or a single node we can simplify your example to the following situation, using element `x` as context node:

```
<doc>
   <contribution speaker-reference="a"/>
   <contribution speaker-reference="b"/>
   <contribution/>
   <x/>
</doc>
```

Selecting `preceding-sibling::contribution[speaker-reference]` returns the two contribution nodes with a `speaker-reference` attribute in document order.

Selecting `(preceding-sibling::contribution[speaker-reference])[1]` returns the first of these two nodes which is the one with `speaker-reference` = a.

Selecting `preceding-sibling::contribution[speaker-reference][1]` the position predicate `[1]` must now be interpreted according the axis order. Since `preceding-sibling` is a reverse axis the selected node-set must treated in reverse document order. The first position in this node-set is the node with `speaker-reference` = b.

Hope this allows you to clarify which implementation has got right.

Comment: I concur. I'm having trouble working out from the description which implementation has the bug, but the correct interpretation is that `ancestor::A[1]/preceding-sibling::x[1]` selects the last matching element in document order, whereas `(ancestor::A[1]/preceding-sibling::x)[1]` selects the first matching element in document order.